# I want to implement OR operator in find() in python

Tags: python, operator-keyword

While compiling the following code i am not getting an syntax error but not all results. The point of the program is to check a string sequence, find some specific substrings in it and print a resulting string having the substring and 19 characters following it. Print each time those strings occurs and every resulting string.

here is the code..

```
x=raw_input('GET STRING:: ');
m=len(x);
k=0;
while(k<m):
    if('AAT'in x or 'AAC' in x or 'AAG' in x):
        start = x.find('AAT') or x.find('AAC') or x.find('AAG')
        end=start+19
        print x[start:end]
```

When I'm inputting a string like ATGGAATCTTGTGATTGCATTGACACGCCATGCCCTGGTGAAGAACTCTTAGTGAAATATCAGTATATCT. It only searches for AAT and prints the resulting substring but not AAG and AAC. Can anyone help me implement the operator???

Comment: When the match is not found, `find` returns `-1` which is not a falsey value.

Comment: You use `k` but don't give it a value.

Comment: The semicolons in your code are completely unneccessary - you only need then if you want to execute multiple statements in one line, e.g. `print(1); print(2)`

Comment: @l4mpi its an old habit.. Tend to give semi colons everywhere

Comment: What if there are less than 19 characters after your search triplet? (Like the last match of `AAT` in your example)

Answer (score 2):

In your example, it's probably better to use a regular expression.

```
>>> text = 'ATGGAATCTTGTGATTGCATTGACACGCCATGCCCTGGTGAAGAACTCTTAGTGAAATATCAGTATATCT'
>>> re.search('(?:AA[TCG])(.{19})', text).group(1)
'CTTGTGATTGCATTGACAC'
```

You could change to `re.findall` if multiple matches are desired from the string. (But this won't work too well if you want over lapping matches (ie, your string of 3 appears again in the 19).

Comment: I want to print all the matches not just one

Comment: @SamFisher Check the link again. EXAct 22 chars.

Comment: @arpit But did not detect overlapping substring. Anyways thanks for your help i did it with re.search as said above.

Comment: @SamFisher If you just wanted the start positions of AAT, AAC or AAG, then you can use `>>> print [m.start() for m in re.finditer('AA[TCG]', text)]
[4, 40, 43, 55]` - but then not all of it is going to be 19 chars after...

Comment: Overlapping matches are no problem for regex if you use lookahead assertions (see my answer).

Answer (score 1):

search for the first occurrence starting from k

```
mystring=raw_input('GET STRING:: ')
m=len(mystring)
k=0
while(k<m):
   x=mystring[k:]
   start=min(x.find('AAT'),x.find('AAC'),x.find('AAG'))
   end=min(start+19,m)
   print x[start:end]
   k+=start+1
```

Comment: I did this and It gives an infinite loop with same results

Comment: @olivier: last line should be: `k = k + end` (because `end` is the position relative to k)

Comment: If you want overlapping matches, just change the last line to: `k = k + start + 1`

Answer (score 0):

You should set `start` to the minimum non-negative value of the three `find` statements.

Comment: i just posted a part of the total code.. k is assigned 0.. I want the program to look up those 3 sub strings and print the resulting 19 char string each time the program find one of those 3 substring..

Comment: olivier has posted a solution implemented according to my answer. It should work provided k is updated correctly.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
import re

str= "ATGGAATCTTGTGATTGCATTGACACGCCATGCCCTGGTGAAGAACTCTTAGTGAAATATCAGTATATCT"
alist = ['AAT','AAC','AAG']
newlist= [re.findall(e,str) for e in alist] 
Output: [['AAT','AAT'],['AAC'],['AAG']].
```

Here a bit heavier with indexes:

```
import re
astr= "ATGGAATCTTGTGATTGCATTGACACGCCATGCCCTGGTGAAGAACTCTTAGTGAAATATCAGTATATCT"
def find_triple_base(astr, nth_sub):
    return [(m.end(), m.group(), astr[m.end(0):m.end(0)+nth_sub]) for m in re.finditer(r'AA[TCG]', astr)]
for e in find_triple_base(astr, 19): print(e)
Output:
(7, 'AAT', 'CTTGTGATTGCATTGACAC')
(43, 'AAG', 'AACTCTTAGTGAAATATCA')
(46, 'AAC', 'TCTTAGTGAAATATCAGTA')
(58, 'AAT', 'ATCAGTATATCT')
```

What it does: findall finds all occurences of your base triples (alist) you'd like to find and generates a new list with 3 lists with base triples eg [['AAT','AAT'],['AAC'],['AAG']]. It's straight forward to print this out.

I hope this helps!

Comment: re.findall doesn't takes the overlapping substrings into consideration

Comment: What does that exactly mean? i.e. in the given string there are two occurences of AAT, both were found. What substrings are you looking for? Just to clear that :)

Answer (score 0):

You can handle overlapping matches with regular expressions that use [lookahead assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) together with a [capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html):

```
>>> import re
>>> regex = re.compile("(?=(AA[TCG].{19}))")
>>> regex.findall("ATGGAATCTTGTGATTGCATTGACACGCCATGCCCTGGTGAAGAACTCTTAGTGAAATATCAGTATATCT")
['AATCTTGTGATTGCATTGACAC', 'AAGAACTCTTAGTGAAATATCA', 'AACTCTTAGTGAAATATCAGTA']
>>>
```

Answer (score -1):

Have a look on this : http://ideone.com/U70n4y

Code:

```
x=raw_input('GET STRING:: ');
m=len(x);
k=0
if('AAT'in x ):
    start = x.find('AAT')
    end=start+19
    print x[start:end]

elif('AAC' in x ):
    start = x.find('AAC')
    end=start+19
    print x[start:end]

elif('AAG' in x):
    start = x.find('AAG')
    end=start+19
    print x[start:end]
```

Edit : try this regexp code

```
import re
y=r"(?:AA[TCG]).{19}"
x=raw_input('GET STRING:: ');
l= re.findall(y,x)
for x in l:
    print x
    print len(x)
```

http://ideone.com/U70n4y

Comment: I'm not sure this is what OP actually wants (the 'elif' part instead of successive ifs), and even if it is, your code is horrible and should really use a loop.

Comment: @l4mpi actually he doesn't say about k. but after reading his comments. i made the appropriate correction.

Comment: @arpit k is 0 as ive said and I would like to use a loop because what ive given is just a part of the program. THere are calculations later on which cannot be implemented like this

Comment: @SamFisher i'm answering the problem you asked in ques. if you want the suggestion for searching in this string then the ans differ. change your ques. title according to your real problem.